# Firebase functions: TypeError: collectionRef.count is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing to an error while following the example of using the count() aggregation from [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries)

My Code is :

```
const collectionRef = db.collection('cities');
const snapshot = await collectionRef.count().get();
const amount = snapshot.data().count;
res.json({ amount });
```

The error says:

> Functions: TypeError: collectionRef.count is not a function

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 6):

The `count()` query was added in [`firebase-admin@11.2.0`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_1120_-_17_october_2022). If you are using an old version, then try updating to latest version.

```
npm i firebase-admin@latest
```

Comment: You are my life saver. Thank you so so much. :)

Comment: Also a big thanks from me